# Deduce the password!

Tags: riddle, password

You have been trapped in a jail cell of an evil mastermind!
The cell has a locked door with a keyboard with the letters a to z and an enter key.
[image: Keyboard]
<sup>([Original image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tastatur-ios7.png?uselang=en-gb) courtesy of Wikimedia Commons)</sup>

The evil mastermind gives you some clues to escape, as he does this as a pastime:

> Only one person has escaped.
>
> They had to figure out the same password as you.
>
> They had a box of clues, which you currently don't have, so he tells you about them.
>
> > This is the tale of my first escapee:
> >     They discovered the clues to the password in a box.
> >     In the box they found a red herring and a butt.
> >     The red herring was way past its time.
> >     The butt was only part of its body, with the rest long risen above.
> >     That was the fate of both of those items.
> >     Using these clues begot the solution to the escapee:
> >     What could've happened to one item to prevent its fate
> >     that would've happened to the second to make it reach its fate?

Note: "they" is used as a gender-neutral third-person pronoun. Can be replaced with "he" or "she".

Comment: Is the spelling of _it's_ intentional?

Comment: No. I still don't get apostrophes in `its` :/

Comment: Is the German keyboard layout of any significance?

Comment: @MarchHo Could not find an English one. No significance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that the answer is

> **smoking**.

The "butt" being referred to is

> the butt of a cigarette. The rest of its body long rose above in puffs of tobacco smoke.

And the red herring is

> one that has been rotten "way past its time". If it had been smoked, it would have lasted longer, "preventing its fate" so to say.

Comment: I feared that if I did that, my entire answer would essentially be a giant spoiler tag, which is against the principle of this site.

Comment: I've edited in order to spoilerise what's essential to the solution without making the entire answer a giant spoiler tag. Feel free to rollback if you object! +1 by the way.

Comment: Won't a better interpretation be that "the herring was rotten, and had it been smoked, its fate (rotting) would have been prevented"?

Comment: @MarchHo That was the intended interpretation.

Comment: I thought that the "fate" of the herring was the one that *would* have happened had it not been smoked. But yes, that would make sense.

Comment: @Reticality You should probably remove your comment if you're really worried about spoilers...

Comment: @Geobits Oops...